# Block-by-Block Matrix Tranpose in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix `a` of the form:

```
> a
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    2
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]    3    4
 [5,]    3    4
 [6,]    3    4
```

I'd like to get the following result:

```
> aprime
       [,1] [,2] [,3] 
  [1,]    1    1    1 
  [2,]    2    2    2 
  [3,]    3    3    3
  [4,]    4    4    4
```

Here is one way to do it:

```
aprime <- matrix(0, 4, 3)
aprime[1:2, ] <- t(a[1:3, ])
aprime[3:4, ] <- t(a[4:6, ])
```

However, this is slow, and I'll need to do this operation many times over on very large matrices.  Another approach:

```
aprime <- matrix(t(a), 4, 3)
```

but that produces

```
> aprime
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    3
 [2,]    2    2    4
 [3,]    1    3    3
 [4,]    2    4    4
```

and finally 
    t(matrix(a, 3, 4))

produces

```
> aprime
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    3    3    3
[3,]    2    2    2
[4,]    4    4    4
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a 3 dimensional array, permute the dimensions and reshape to a matrix:

```
matrix(aperm(array(a, c(3, 2, 2)), 3:1), 4)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4
```

**Note:** `a` in reproducible form is:

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4), 6)
```